# How to Draw These As Functions In Tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am aiming to make a simulated plot that looks SOMETHING like [image: this] however I have not been able to get the lines to match up. Please assist if you could!

Comment: Hi Oscar, welcome to the site. It is certainly possible that you ask follw up questions relating to your previous questions. However, it would be best if you can also build up the question such as what was the previous question and what is the new problem and so on such that we can follow your issue. Otherwise this is just a duplicate and we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (4,1.6) to[out=24,in=265] (7.5,5);
\draw[thick,red] (0.2,-0.2) -- (6.9,2.5) to[out=-90,in=225] (7.5,2.9)
to[out=45,in=135] (8.1,3.16);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```